# Recuperar las rutas de mis fotos guardadas en mysql

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Recuperar las rutas de mis fotos guardadas en mysql mediante javascript y ajax.

Necesito un ciclo que me ayude a recorrer los objetos de mi respuesta con ajax, la idea es extrar las rutas separadas por como en mi campo para poder incluirlas en un append con js y recuperarlas en mi html

```javascript
$(".tablas tbody").on("click", "button.btnVerEvidencias", function() {
  var idEvidencias = $(this).attr("idEvidencias");
  console.log("idEvidencias", idEvidencias);
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("idEvidencias", idEvidencias);
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/ventas.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(respuesta) {
      $("#media").append();
    }
  })
})


Respuesta del ajax
....
evidencia: "vistas/img/tickets/10100/descarga (2).jpg,vistas/img/tickets/10100/descarga.jpg,vistas/img/tickets/10100/desc
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es el formato de _respuesta_? Puedes ponerlo en la pregunta... conociendo que es lo que responde _ventas.ajax.php_ en _respuesta_, es probable que te puedan ayudar de mejor forma

Comment: Cuál lenguaje utilizas para el `backend`?... Si necesitas un `string` separado por comas, tal vez sea más fácil obtenerlo desde este recurso con un ciclo o algo parecido. Agrega más detalles a la pregunta, por favor.

Comment: Utilizo php como lenguaje de backend

Answer (score 1):

si la respuesta es un simple string podes agregar dentro del success de ajax lo siguiente

```
var arreglo = respuesta.split(',');
arreglo.forEach( function(item){
    console.log(item);
});
```

En la primer linea divido el string buscando comas en un array y despues lo recorro. Con el console.log lo mando a la consola para que puedas chequearlo desde la consola del navegador.